# How to use sorting to arrange a list of words based on length, when equal use alphabetical order?(without comparison tools)

Tags: sorting, string-length, alphabetical-sort

How to use sorting to arrange a list of words based on length, when equal use alphabetical order? (without comparison tools)

Comment: Yes: 1) compare on length. 2) if the lengths happen to be equal: compare on contents.

Comment: Please clarify.  What do you mean by 'comparison tool'?  What have you done so far?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear (please vote to close if you are able to do so)

Answer (score -1):

Sort the list *twice*: First alphabetically, then by length. This will give you a list sorted by length, and then alphabetically for words of the same length. For example:

```
at
by
bat
cat
dog
aardvark
```

Is this what you need? Or do you need sample code as well?

Comment: This might have been downvoted because the OP is either lazy or a help vampire, and there is an unwritten rule not to feed such individuals.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. But why was my *answer* down-voted?

Comment: That was my point - perhaps someone felt you were feeding a vampire, and that whilst vampires themselves should be downvoted, perhaps people encouraging them to stay ought to be discouraged too. (I personally don't downvote for this reason, but I do sometimes add a comment to achieve the same).